# Count previous elements that have the local-name() equal to 'FootNoteReference'

Tags: xslt

How can I count how many previous **FootNoteReference** nodes there are in an xml doc such as this...

```
<MyDoc>
<title>&lt;Big Title&gt;</title>
<head>Objective</head>
<head2>&lt;Heading&gt;</head2>
<head>Introduction</head>
<Para>
    asdf asdf asdf asd<FootNoteReference />asdf asdf asfd asfd 
</Para>
<head>Overview</head>
<Para>
    &lt;Begin with a definition of the class to which<FootNoteReference /> the categories belong, if required.&gt;
</Para>
<Para>&lt;List the different categories to be taught.&gt;</Para>
<Heading1>&lt;Category 1&gt;</Heading1>
<Para>&lt; som neodolal a celé ozdobené spústou prachu v jednom preso&gt;</Para>
<Para>&lt;Provide examples, if required.&gt;</Para>
<Heading1>&lt;Category 2&gt;</Heading1>
<Para>&lt; som neodolal a celé ozdobené spústou prachu v jednom preso&gt;</Para>
<Para>&lt;Provide examples, if required.&gt;</Para>
<Heading1>&lt;Category 3&gt;</Heading1>
<Para>
    &lt;Provide a description<FootNoteReference /> of the third category as outlined in the list.&gt;
</Para>
<Para>&lt;Provide examples, if required.&gt;</Para>
<head>Summary</head>
<ListItem type="ul">&lt;Summarize the definition, if applicable.&gt;</ListItem>
<ListItem type="ul">&lt; som neodolal a celé ozdobené spústou prachu v jednom preso<FootNoteReference />.&gt;</ListItem>
<ListItem type="ul">&lt; som neodolal a celé ozdobené spústou prachu v jednom preso&gt;</ListItem></MyDoc>
```

Notice how the **FootNoteReference** node is nested at different levels.  I know if they were all nested at the same level I could do: `count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = 'FootNoteReference'])`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [**"`preceding`" axis**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#axes):

**`count($vNode/preceding::FootNoteReference)`**

is the number of `FootNoteReference` elements that precede the node referenced by `$vNode`.

If the node is a descendent of any `FootNoteReference` element and you want also to count its ancestor `FootNoteReference` elements, then the occurences of the `FootNoteReference` element on [**the "`ancestor`" axis**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#axes) should also be accounted for, and this will be accomplished by the following XPath expression:

**`count($vNode/preceding::FootNoteReference` 

              `|` 
                `$vNode/ancestor::FootNoteReference)`**

Comment: Thanks for the help. This did the trick: select="count(preceding::FootNoteReference)